# Word for a style of argument pre-excluding a particular answer as impossible

Tags: american-english, rhetoric

I'm not sure if this is a type of fallacy, or merely a noun or adjective for a type of (obstinate) argument.

I'm looking for a word that describes a situation where a person is demanding an answer or output, but has already decided that one answer or output is unacceptable - and demands continued attempts at devising an argument or process that will generate an answer or output that is not the "forbidden" one.

I believe I've come across a term like this before, but cannot remember it. If I did come across such a term, it probably would have been in the context of computer programming, or data analysis, or philosophy.

Comment: Do you mean precluding (instead of "pre-excluding")? Possibly also the answer to your question.

Comment: Precluding may be a better formulation within the question than "pre-excluding", but I'm really looking for a word for the next step - where, having precluded one answer, the questioner demands that you continue to hunt for a different one and/or that you revise your method so that it doesn't generate the precluded answer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question for ELU. Rhetoric is a vast discipline in its own right. You may find this [extensive list of rhetorical devices](http://phrontistery.info/rhetoric.html) helpful. Your word is probably there somewhere.

Comment: This is simply a problem with constraints.  (I need a way to get across  the river, and I don’t want a boat. (still leaving bridges, planes, tunnels, etc))  Whether the constraints are too restrictive to allow any solution is a secondary issue. And whether the taskmaster continues the search even after the problem is shown to be overconstrained is a third issue. (This is called ***folly***)

Comment: It's definitely folly! I just wasn't sure if this type of folly had its own name.  I am thinking, in particular, of cases where the precluded answer was the correct one all along, but additional effort is invested in finding a different answer because the precluded answer "cannot" be conceded to be true or allowed to be true.

Comment: @WS2 Should I remove the question, or should I add the rhetoric tag?

Comment: @tbrookside Might be an idea to add the rhetoric tag, if there is one.

Comment: The term is "Loaded question" and the textbook example is "Have you stopped beating your wife?"